# How to make Google Maps direction using android?

Tags: android, google-maps, directions

Does Google Maps API add-on for Android SDK support the routing(directions) functions on Google maps. 
If No, is there any good method to be used in implementing a directions for Google maps on android

The DrivingDirection package (com.google.googlenav.DrivingDirection) is removed since Android SDK 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get driving directions from src to destination.

use following method to get driving directions in arrayList

```
private ArrayList<String> getDirectionData(String srcPlace, String destPlace) {

        String urlString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr="
                + srcPlace + "&daddr=" + destPlace
                + "&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml";
        Log.d("URL", urlString);
        Document doc = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;
        ArrayList<String> pathConent = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            url = new URL(urlString.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("LineString");
        for (int s = 0; s < nl.getLength(); s++) {
            Node rootNode = nl.item(s);
            NodeList configItems = rootNode.getChildNodes();
            for (int x = 0; x < configItems.getLength(); x++) {
                Node lineStringNode = configItems.item(x);
                NodeList path = lineStringNode.getChildNodes();
                pathConent.add(path.item(0).getNodeValue());
            }
        }
        placeMarks=new ArrayList<String>();
        NodeList place=doc.getElementsByTagName("Placemark");
        for(int i=0;i<place.getLength();i++){
            Node root=place.item(i);
            NodeList config=root.getChildNodes();
                Node placenode=config.item(0);
                NodeList name=placenode.getChildNodes();
                placeMarks.add(name.item(0).getNodeValue());
                Log.i("Node Value: ", ""+name.item(0).getNodeValue());

        }
        placeMarks.remove((placeMarks.size()-1));
        Log.i("LineString: ", pathConent.get(0));
        ArrayList<String> tmpcoords=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<pathConent.size();i++){
            tmpcoords.addAll(Arrays.asList(pathConent.get(i).split(" ")));
        }
        //String[] tempContent = pathConent.split(" ");
        return placeMarks;
    }
```

Comment: yes I have already found it , but I don't from where to get "com.google.googlenav"-Package

Comment: @llango The DrivingDirection package (com.google.googlenav.DrivingDirection) is removed since Android SDK 1.1.

Comment: now i gave code in edited post. use that code and call this method getDirectionData(String srcPlace, String destPlace) this will return driving directions list.

Comment: Does it use the Noraml Google Directinos API as a web service ?